# Ember Data: Can I add extra properties when persisting data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

There's a route on our API to create a `production` with a POST to `/productions`. We have the option of passing a `project_id` property with the body to attach the production to a project in one go. So the request would looks as follows:

```
// POST to /productions

{
  title: "Production Title",
  goal_date: "2015-04-30 01:37:03",
  project_id: "prj_hash123"
}
```

When I `store.createRecord('production', { title: "Production Title", ... });`, the `project_id` property is stripped off and not sent with the `save()`. Is there a way using Ember Data to send along this request with the extra property?

Note: I have already tried modifying the `RESTSerializer.serialize` method, but the `project_id property` doesn't even make it there. I assume because it's not defined on the model, it's stripped when `createRecord` is called.

Comment: so, `project_id` is not part of `production` model?

Comment: No, it's not. I want to pass it in so when I save(), it gets passed with the request. Our API does this to create the relationship between projects and productions.

Comment: Could you just add `project_id` to the `production` model and set it when you are creating records?

Comment: I suppose that would work for this scenario. What about other scenarios where this isn't possible? Is $.ajax calls with store.pushPayload the best way to go?